# Can't provide version ranges in the maven dependency management import scope

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, versioning

I have a large java project managed using maven. 
We are using Maven 3 for management (specifically  3.6.0).

In the project, there is a sub=project with a `runtime-v5.pom.xml`.
In said `pom`, there is a version property

```
<properties>
    <platform-v5.version>73.2.05</platform-v5.version>
</properties>
```

Which is used later in the file

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.thing.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-parent</artifactId>
            <version>${platform-v5.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.release</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-v5</artifactId>
            <version>${platform-v5.version}</version>
            <type>resolved-pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

My goal is to get maven to pull in the most recent version of platform and I don't want to update the version in this file every time. I thought that changing the specific version to a range would allow the project to always pull in the most recent version in accordance with the given range.

When the `platform-v5.version` is set to a specific existing version, it builds just fine, but when setting the version to a range such as `[73.2.05,)`, I get errors such as

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading from all_global_universal: https://nexus.company/platform-parent/%5B73.2.05,).pom
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact com.company.thing.platform:platform-parent:pom:[73.2.05,) in all_global_universal (https://nexus.company/content/groups/all_global_universal) @ com.company:runtime-v5:[unknown-version], path/to/runtime-v5.pom.xml, line XX, column YY
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.company:runtime-v5:1.0.2 (path/to/runtime-v5.pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact com.company.thing.platform:platform-parent:pom:[73.2.05,) in all_global_universal (https://nexus.company/content/groups/all_global_universal) @ com.company:runtime-v5:[unknown-version], path/to/runtime-v5.pom.xml, line XX, column YY -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Essentially, I want to know: **Why can't you provide version ranges in the maven dependency management import scope?**

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [Using maven dependency management import scope with version ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969586/using-scope-import-with-version-ranges/71023321)

This Maven issue was resolved and will be released in Maven 4.0.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4463

Answer (score 0):

While version ranges are not exactly deprecated, they are no longer considered a best practise. The modern way would be to run an appropriate update goal before the build so that the version numbers in the pom are the newest ones available.

Comment: When trying to run `mvn versions:resolve-ranges --file runtime-v5.pom.xml` mvn still can't seem to parse the version range; it throws the same errors as listed above. I've run this command with other `pom` files in the same project, and the command works fine. Do you have any recommendations on why this might be?

Comment: I don't know whether the goal can resolve properties properly.